# Need help in Bootstrap columns

Tags: css, bootstrap-4

I am trying to write an address field. I want the State and Country block on the right side of the city and postal code.

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">

<div class="col-sm-12 col-md-6 col-lg-6">

  <div class="need-info">
    <p class="info-title">Enter Your Address.</p>
    <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Address line 1.">
  </div>

  <div class="need-info">
    <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Address line 2.">
  </div>
</div>
<div class="col-sm-12 col-md-3 col-lg-3">
  <div class="need-info">
    <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="City">
  </div>
  <div class="need-info">
    <input type="number" class="form-control" placeholder="Postal Code">
  </div>
</div>
<div class="col-sm-12 col-md-3 col-lg-3">
  <div class="need-info">
    <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="State">
  </div>
  <div class="need-info">
    <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Country">
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Minor tweaking in your existing code to get what you're looking for...

- on small size, occupy all 12 columns
- else 6 columns for postal code, city, country & state

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">


<div class="col-sm-12 col-md-12 ">

  <div class="need-info">
    <p class="info-title">Enter Your Address.</p>
    <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Address line 1.">
  </div>

  <div class="need-info">
    <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Address line 2.">
  </div>
</div>
<div class="col-sm-12 col-md-12 col-lg-12">
  <div class='row'>
    <div class="col-12 col-sm-6">
      <div class="need-info">
        <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="City">
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-12 col-sm-6 ">
      <div class="need-info">
        <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="state">
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-12 col-sm-6 ">
      <div class="need-info">
        <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="postal code">
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-12 col-sm-6 ">
      <div class="need-info">
        <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="country">
      </div>

    </div>

  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try with this structure.

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">

<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-12">
        <div class="need-info">
            <p class="info-title">Enter Your Address.</p>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Address line 1.">
        </div>
        <div class="need-info">
            <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Address line 2.">
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-6">
        <div class="need-info">
            <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="City">
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-6">
        <div class="need-info">
            <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="State">
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-6">
        <div class="need-info">
            <input type="number" class="form-control" placeholder="Postal Code">
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-6">
        <div class="need-info">
            <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Country">
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```